# How can I speed up a Postgres query, in which I want to query all entries within a date range

Tags: postgresql

So I'm doing this query

```
select * from table where time>'2019-01-28 04:13:36.790000' and time<'2019-01-28 04:13:46.790000';
```

It used to be very fast, but as the table grew it's now taking several minutes to complete. I'm not exactly sure how many entries are in the table. I'm guessing tens of millions. I just want to be able to query entries in a given time interval. Is there anything I can do to the table to make this quicker.

Comment: Depending on how often you query it, partitions may also be quite effective.  Tens of millions of rows warrants partitioning IMO if you are reading from that table frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without more context, but if you don't already have an [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html) on `time`, consider adding one.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_time ON table (time ASC)
```